# Paste Group of Charts as Pictures

Tags: excel, vba, image, paste, excel-charts

I want to send a daily distribution of charts in an Excel workbook.

In my master file, the chart ranges are updated each day.
I am sending the charts as pictures to help with easier viewing.

I distribute the charts in 2 columns, hence the modulus operator.
Each chart's size is 25 rows and 13 columns.

```vb
Sub ChartPasteValues()

Dim wb As Workbook, aWs As Worksheet, bWs As Worksheet, cht As ChartObject
Dim PasteRow As Integer, count As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set aWs = wb.Worksheets("Charts Master")
Set bWs = wb.Worksheets("Charts Output")

'delete all the prior day's charts in the output worksheet
    bWs.Pictures.Delete

'paste as pictures all of today's charts
    count = 1
    PasteRow = 2
    For Each cht In aWs.ChartObjects
        cht.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
        If count Mod 2 = 1 Then
            bWs.Range("B" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            count = count + 1
        Else
            bWs.Range("M" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            PasteRow = PasteRow + 25
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cht
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What’s the problem?